# Debug loading issue

Tags: magento, debugging, nginx

I'm having trouble debugging an extremely strange bug.

It happens rarely, and at seemingly random places on the page.

The HTML will stop, and start loading the page again - see screenshot below:

[image]

If I reload the page then 99% of the time it works fine. We're using Magento on an nginx server but the issue also happens on my local dev box.

There are no errors generated when this happens that I can see (checked nginx, php-fpm, mysql and Magento logs).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could debug this issue?

Comment: have you checked if it has onload function applied by mistake ?

Comment: Is it furiously reloading continuously or is it just one reload ?

Comment: php version? using APC? if so, which version?

Comment: we need more info about your environment

Comment: This is just one page load. It doesnt carry on trying to load repeatedly.

Environment is outdated, but we can't update due to legacy requirements. PHP 5.3 with APC 3.1.9, and also using Redis. Is there anything I should look for in the stats on apc.php that could help see if that is having issues?

Comment: High fragmentation on APC might cause these problems. try disabling that extension

Comment: Just checked in apc.php and fragmentation is reported as 2.69% ( 6.2 MBytes out of 230.5 MBytes in 22 fragments). This seems low to me, having seen other reports of people with 100% fragmentation...

Comment: try anyway disabling that. also, post the output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: At what point does the HTML stops? I'll start by determining if it's a JS or PHP issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your **javascript** in your **template** or **skin**. When dom is ready the search filter will load their subcategory also.

You should have a look at Network tab in debug tool and check the last request is called by **Ajax** (XHR). Maybe it is rendering a page layout template instead of **json** or **blank page**.

Good luck